# Порог вхождения в язык: чем меньше, тем лучше?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, php, ruby, django

Встал вопрос выбрать язык для дальнейшего развития.  Программирую на php 2 года.
Какой язык выбрать python/django или ruby on rails? У какого языка больше перспективы?

Comment: Мне кажется, напрасно вы ждёте объективизма, задавая подобный вопрос. Каждый будет расхваливать то, что знает/умеет готовить. :)

Comment: продолжайте писать на php. нормальных пхпешников не так уж много

Comment: http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

Comment: Ага, VB на 12ом, а JS на 10ом, нуну

Comment: Для дальнейшего развития углубитесь в теорию: алгоритмы, паттерны, дискретная математика, операционные системы, теория баз данных и т.п. Иначе хорошим программистом не стать.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, а что Вас так удивило в сравнении JS с VB?

IMHO количество web страничек c JS просто обязано быть огромным.

    TIOBE Programming Community index is an indicator of the popularity of programming languages.
    ....
    Observe that the TIOBE index is not about the best programming language or the language in which most lines of code have been written.
    ....
    The ratings are calculated by counting hits of the most popular search engines.

поэтому неудивительно, что людей, которых в данный момент интересует JS раза в 2 больше, чем интересующихся VB.

Comment: @avp - вы меня не верно поняли, я к тому, что я не могу согласиться с тем, что front end language of the web занимает всего-лишь 10ую позицию. По факту, на JS, в той или иной степени, пишут практически все девы, независимо от ЯП

Comment: > По факту, на JS, в той или иной степени, пишут практически все девы, независимо от ЯП

Это откуда такие факты, интересно?

Comment: @falstaf - я говорю о web development'e и говорю лишь о том, что каждый день вижу своими глазами.

Comment: А как же новомодный CoffeeScript, всякие там haxe, gwt, vaadin и прочее? Ну да, в итоге оно транслируется в JS, но разработчик то всё же пишет не на нём.

Comment: @falstaf - мне не интересно холиварить

Comment: Тем лучше для чего?

Comment: У языков программирования, библиотек и прочих фреймворков есть только одна перспектива — использоваться, до тех пор, пока эти вещи не умрут от старости. Пузомерки TIOBE-шмиобе… когда технологии популярны настолько, что для каждой открыто 100500+ позиций — эти рейтинги ничего осмысленного не значат.

Пока и Ruby, и Python, и их экосистемы пребывают в относительно добром здравии, и помирать не собираются. Вопрос же кто в будущем быстрее отправится к праотцам — это не сюда, а на «битву экстрасенсов.» И, если что — даже труп Кобола, вон, до сих пор иногда шевелится и замогильно завывает.

Dixi.

Comment: @Gedweb holy war detected улыбнуло)))

Answer (score 7):

Присмотритесь к **JavaScript**, я думаю, что у языка большие перспективы. Node.js - для программирования на стороне сервера (Backend), jQuery, Sencha и еще куча фреймворков для клиентской разработки + под Win 8 можно писать десктопные приложения.

Comment: в Gnome3 JavaScript и CSS применяются для интерактивности и оформления

Comment: посмотрите список пакетов Ubuntu, вы удивитесь как там много питона

Comment: как же linux без убунточки раньше жил?

Если вы туда ещё смотрите, то я давно в курсе, что минимум треть софта linux на python'e
Однако, его использование в веб и на других платформах мало распространено и перспективы у данного языка мало, в отличии от JS.

P.S. сам я в основном PHP-developer

Comment: Я не являюсь сотрудником [этой компании][1], но могу точно сказать что они легко могут оспорить ваше мнение. 

ЗЫ:
Сам я писал на python'e, сейчас работаю с java ee.


  [1]: http://steelkiwi.com/

Comment: Перспективы у JS в области разработки бэкэндов (Node.js) весьма сомнительные, на данный момент это прерогатива лишь энтузиастов да небольших компаний.

Enterprise-рынок стабильно уж как много лет держит Java, нишу широко масштабируемых отказоустойчивых серверных решений - Erlang и, в меньшей степени, Haskell.

Так что, сегодня JS - лишь инструмент фронтэндера, не более.

Comment: вот и приехали, у вас java...

я подписан на рассылку Hantim, постоянно требуются php и java разработчики, очень редко Ruby на рельсах и python (в любом виде)

Comment: Мы сравниваем количество проектов на Java/PHP, или уровень зарплат в секторе и востребованность специалистов (именно специалистов а не хоумпэйдждевелоперов)?

Если по количеству проектов, то тут у PHP мало конкурентов, конечно. :)

А рассылка хантима - это да, показатель. Вне всякого сомнения.

Comment: Хмм...сомнительность Node.js сомнительна =) ВКонтакте, Linkedin, Яндекс, mail.ru все так или иначе используют ноду...

Comment: Linkedin - java. По ВКонтакте, яндексу и мэйлу - ничего сказать не могу, не располагаю такой информацией. Ссылочкой на пруф не поделитесь?

Comment: holy war detected

Comment: Мобильный Linkedin мигрировал с руби на ноду http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/10/Ruby-on-Rails-Node-js-LinkedIn

ВКонтакте юзает ноду для XMPP (чатик и уведомления) http://www.insight-it.ru/masshtabiruemost/arkhitektura-vkontakte/

Яндекс использовал ноду в почте опять же для чата (который прикрыли)

Comment: @falstaf по поводу linkedin, если написано что они используют ноду это вовсе не значит что везде. По поводу yandex, mail.ru, VK - гугль в помощь, ну и, так сказать, для общего развития - JS на сервере это не только Node.

Ну и еще, тех кто до сиих пор сомневается в том, что Node уже prod ready - список тех, кто с вами [не согласен](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node) (он, естественно, далеко не полный, но linkedin, например, там есть)

Ну и в завершение - джависты, нравиться вам или нет, а JS рулит :)

Comment: Фразы типа "%language_name% рулит" давайте оставим студентам и холиварщикам и будем выбирать инструмент согласно условиям задачи и требованиям проекта. Фанатизм не есть признак профессионализма.

Comment: @Gedweb по поводу вакансий, именно по этому я и перешел на java :D, хотя вакансий по Москве на питонщиков от 80-90 тыс рублей достаточно много, но я то в Киеве

Comment: @falstaf так все началось с безобидного предложения JavaScript как языка и тут понеслась =) Так что "мопед не мой" =)

Comment: Спустя десять лет…

Answer (score 3):

Имхо, выбор языка практически ничего не значит для развития как специалиста и профессиональной востребованности в будущем. Да и вообще, вы сравниваете фреймворки, а не ЯП.

Субъективно - по Python встречаю вакансий/заказов больше, чем на Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить о пороге вхождения, то для программиста он чем ниже, тем, наверное, лучше (хотя, это все же неоднозначное утверждение). А для работодателя, скорее всего, низкий порог вождения не так уж хорош - придется выбирать среди стада кодообезьян, которые пишут за кусок хлеба именно на %language_name% из-за его простоты, и вследствие этого не в растут профессиональном плане

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что вы программировали на php (а значит для веба), я бы посоветовал вам присмотреться к ruby (и ruby on rails в частности). Ruby как язык не лучше и не хуже Python`а, но Ruby On Rails как веб-фреймворк - лучше Django, Pylons, Yii и т.д. RoR - законодатель мод, если можно так выразиться, среди фреймворков. Много книг, документации, примеров, и одно из самых больших сообществ по фреймворкам.